# Facebook login, redirect to server then app

Tags: javascript, python, facebook, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to login via FB in my app (written using jQuery Mobile and wrapped with phonegap build). When I click on the link the app opens

myserver.com/login

At this point the server (python) calls FB login function. Once the user has logged in FB will redirect to my server again, where I'll do some stuff.

Now, how can I redirect from my server back to my app? I tried to pass

```
document.URL
```

to the server and redirect there but my phone says I don't have permission to acces file://android_asset/www/index.html

Thanks to anyone who is willing/able to help.

Comment: In php I would use header(), but that's probably not your problem...

Comment: @Konstantin actually what I don't understand is to which URL the server should redirect to after it gets the reply from FB auth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using childbrowser plugin.

In phonegap build

https://build.phonegap.com/docs/plugins